# Apex - Default options for widget/component type

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I know I can specify init options for single widgets in *"Advanced - Javascript Initialization Code"* section in page builder, using the following syntax:

```
function (options) {

    ....

    return options;

}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a way of doing the same for all components of a type (i.e. *interactiveGrid*) in the same application/workspace.

Maybe inside a shared js file referenced in *"User Interface"* section, or inside *"Global"* (page 0).

No idea how to do this at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic action to execute Javascript on the Page Load Event in the global page (page 0).

Comment: Ok, but what about which syntax to use? The one above can be used too?